# Accessibility Element for a point

Tags: iphone, accessibility

Trying to determine based on a CGPoint inside a window, what (if any) accessibility element is hit.  Is this possible?  Sort of an Accessibility Element hit test...  Should return any accessibility element hit (including System created).  Seems like there has to be a way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fear that in order to achieve what you want, you’ll have to basically re-implement how e.g. browsers do the capture phase in their event handling in the DOM:

- Start at the most general element — in any UIKit-based app, this will be the application’s `keyWindow` or (if your App is multiscreen) the front most window of the screen which you’ll have to figure out through the `windowLevel` etc.
- Check whether the object in question is an accessibility-container, and

  - if so, recurse into that, asking for the appropriate thing.
  - If it's not, check whether it is an accessibility-element, and

    - if it’s not bail.
    - If it is, check whether its accessibility-frame contains the point in question.
    - Now if *that* happens to be the case, congratulations: You have succeeded in finding the element in question, so you should return it.
    - If that isn’t so, bail.

By now, we have handled the cases accessibility-element and element inside container.

There is one additional case to cover and that are accessibility-containers, which are themselves accessibility-elements:
We have a container, that did not yield an element for the point in question.

If it is an accessibility-element, check whether its frame contains the point, and
- if so, return `self`,
- if not, bail.

And by bail I always mean return nil.

Now grab all that logic, turn it into code, and put it in a category on `NSObject`.

Comment: This seems to be what I was looking for.  Haven't had a chance to test it though.

Answer (score 0):

My best answer would be:
Add all the accessibility elements to an array.
In your touchesEnded method, enumerate through the array and check to see if any of the elements have been touched. One way to do this is to check to see if the boundingBox of the element contains the CGPoint.
Then you can write a bunch of code to respond to that touch!
Hope this helped! ^_^

Comment: Sadly doesn't answer my question...  The accessibility elements I am trying to determine are in UI created by iOS...  for instance, keyboard UI.

Comment: Closest to answering actual question.

Answer (score 0):

two possible ways to do that. **First one**, you create a category of `UIView` (New File, Category, name it "tapped", subclass of "UIView") and put this code in it:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    NSLog(@"%@", self);
}
```

so far this code will work with all `UIView`s but not with all subclasses of itself. So you need to create some more subclasses (eg. `UIControl`, `UIWindow`, etc.). In those subclasses you don't need to `NSLog()` anything, just call:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

because all those subclasses will call the superclass they will end up calling the `NSLog()` of `UIView`. The downside you have to create an immense amount of subclasses for all cases. For example you need `UIView` for `UIControl`, then `UIControl` for `UIButton` and so on.

.

**The other way** isn't exactly what you asked for, but is much easier. Simply call subviews recursively.

```
- (void)logView:(UIView*)v index:(int)i
{
    NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString string];
    for (int u = 0; u<i; u++) { [str appendString:@"| "]; }
    [str appendFormat:@"<%@ %p frame:%@>", v.class, v, NSStringFromCGRect(v.frame)];
    // of course you can change it to display your accessibility hint/label
    printf("%s\n", [str UTF8String]);

    for (UIView *vv in v.subviews) { [self logView:vv index:i+1]; }
}
```

you call this method once:

```
[self logView:self.view index:0];
```

… and it will automatically create a tree as output:

```
<UITextField 0x6b30010 frame:{{20, 13}, {280, 31}}>
| <UITextFieldRoundedRectBackgroundView 0x6b31e00 frame:{{0, 0}, {280, 31}}>
| | <UIImageView 0x6b31fe0 frame:{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}>
| | <UIImageView 0x6b32070 frame:{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}>
| | <UIImageView 0x6b320e0 frame:{{0, 0}, {0, 0}}>
```

Comment: Think you missed the question :)  Not trying to find the hit view.. but trying to find the hit UIAccessibilityElement...  Which aren't always views (there is a way to define a UIAccessibilityElement area for when there are no views present, that gets used quite frequently).  Also, hitTest is a method that will often return the view that was hit (though it won't return non-interactive elements).

Comment: ahh ok now I got it. Tried some things but didn't get success either :/ actually I didn't even get any accessibility -.- Do I have to enable it in a hidden place? I set a label and hint for an UI element and then asked via code `NSLog(@"%@", [itm accessibilityHint]);` result: `(null)` WHAT? `accessibilityElementCount` is unnatural and `self.accessibilityElementAtIndex:` is always `(null)`. Accessibility inspector shows correct. And categories on `UIAccessibilityElement` don't work either *phu*

Comment: It's there, you can create your own elements, and if you turn on accessibility in settings (for simulator) then you can actually see the elements... somehow Apple knows when the user touches an area what the related accessibility element is, but so far it seems that they aren't sharing that information :(

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it seems like there is no way to do this with the latest API.